# Firefox prints text properly and images reversed

Tags: firefox, printer, mirroring, images

If I print a webpage from Firefox 3.6.6 to my HP deskjet 990cxi printer (USB connection), the text is printed normally, but the images are reversed (mirror image).

This hasn't always happened, but seems to have been a "feature" of at least the last few versions of Firefox.

If I select the print option for Mirror Image then the image is OK, but the text is reversed.

I've seen a few other posts scattered over the web from people with the same issue, but no sign of a cause or solution. eg http://support.mozilla.com/en-US/forum/1/378421

By the way, the problem doesn't happen with IE 7

Comment: Have you tried switching off all your plugins and addons to see if one of those is causing it?

Answer (score 1):

I would [create a new Firefox profile](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Creating_a_new_Firefox_profile_on_Windows) and see if the issue still occurs:

- If it does still happen, this suggests that it is either an configuration option in your printer that was changed at some point in the past or some other piece of software on your computer is interfering with Firefox's print settings.
- If the issue stops happening, you can either continue to use the new profile and [import your old data and settings](http://kb.mozillazine.org/Transferring_data_to_a_new_profile_-_Firefox) (avoiding importing print settings), or go back to the old profile and try to figure out which setting is causing this issue.